# How to refresh access_token on server side(JAVA)?

Tags: spring-boot, google-drive-api, google-signin

I am using a spring boot as my backend application.
I have stored our client's *access_token*, *refresh_token*, and *access_id* in my postgresql database.

Here is my code trying to get the new access token if token expired.

```
public void refreshGoogleIdToken(GoogleAuthEntity googleAuthEntity) {
        LOGGER.debug("GoogleAuthService.refreshGoogleIdToken()");
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(transport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setClientSecrets(googleAuthClientId, googleAuthClientSecret)
                .build();
        credential.setAccessToken(googleAuthEntity.getAccessToken());
        credential.setRefreshToken(googleAuthEntity.getRefreshToken());
        try {
            if (credential.refreshToken()) {
                Long newExpireTime = credential.getExpirationTimeMilliseconds();
                String newAccessToken = credential.getAccessToken();
                String newRefreshToken = credential.getRefreshToken();
                LOGGER.debug("NewAccessToken: " + newAccessToken);
                LOGGER.debug("NewRefreshToken: " + newRefreshToken);
                LOGGER.debug("NewExpireTime: " + newExpireTime);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.debug("GoogleAuthService.refreshGoogleIdToken() - IOException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Google return 400 error, and the description is: 400 Bad Request

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Bad Request"
}
```

What mistake that I have make?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have been using OAuth2 with spring framework and have only encountered this error *"Invalid grant"* in case if **refresh token is invalid, expired, revoked or does not match the redirection uri used in the authorization request, or is issued to another client**

For your situation I think you should delete the stored refresh token / rectify it and debug your code again. This may be due to wrong token info stored in your PostgreSQL database while testing.